# Python threading sequence

Tags: python, python-multithreading

Here is a sample program that I ran to test thread sequence for Python

```
import threading
import time
import logging
import random

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,
        format = '%(asctime)s (%(threadName)-10s) %(message)s')

def worker():
        t = threading.currentThread()
        pause = random.randint(1,10)
        logging.debug('sleeping %s', pause)
        time.sleep(pause)
        logging.debug('ending sleep')
        return

for i in range(3):
        t = threading.Thread(target=worker,name='t%s'%i)
        t.setDaemon(True)
        t.start()

main_thread = threading.currentThread()
for t in threading.enumerate():
        if t is main_thread:
                continue
        logging.debug('joining %s', t.getName())
        t.join()
```

Here is the output of a program run:

```
2016-11-22 12:59:12,052 (t0        ) sleeping 3
2016-11-22 12:59:12,052 (t1        ) sleeping 3
2016-11-22 12:59:12,052 (t2        ) sleeping 8
2016-11-22 12:59:12,052 (MainThread) joining t0
2016-11-22 12:59:15,055 (t0        ) ending sleep
2016-11-22 12:59:15,056 (MainThread) joining t2
2016-11-22 12:59:15,056 (t1        ) ending sleep
2016-11-22 12:59:20,054 (t2        ) ending sleep
2016-11-22 12:59:20,054 (MainThread) joining t1
```

Notice the joining order is not consistent with either enumerate list order, or with the timing order. The joining order of the main thread should invoke t0 -> t1 -> t2 thread sequence, but it is to -> t2 -> t1.

What is happening here?

Comment: why would you assume that threading.enumerate() would return them in the same order you created them?

Comment: Step 1 in Learning to Multithread: Your threads will go in whatever order they like, and there's nothing you can do about it. (Well, you can. But if you do you are losing any and all gains you were hoping to achieve with multithreading.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`threading.enumerate()` doesn't say anything about the order in which it enumerates the threads. Looking at the source, threads are tracked in two `dict`'s called `_active` and `_limbo`. When you enumerate, you enumerate the keys of these dictionaries and their order is not defined.

Joining threads this way is risky. You accounted for main thread, but what if you imported a module that uses background threads for its own purposes? Instead, keep your own list

```
import threading
import time
import logging
import random

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,
        format = '%(asctime)s (%(threadName)-10s) %(message)s')

def worker():
        t = threading.currentThread()
        pause = random.randint(1,10)
        logging.debug('sleeping %s', pause)
        time.sleep(pause)
        logging.debug('ending sleep')
        return

threads = []

for i in range(3):
        t = threading.Thread(target=worker,name='t%s'%i)
        t.setDaemon(True)
        t.start()
        threads.append(t)

for t in threads:
        logging.debug('joining %s', t.getName())
        t.join()
```

Output is

```
2016-11-22 15:16:51,230 (t0        ) sleeping 10
2016-11-22 15:16:51,232 (t1        ) sleeping 8
2016-11-22 15:16:51,233 (t2        ) sleeping 4
2016-11-22 15:16:51,234 (MainThread) joining t0
2016-11-22 15:16:55,235 (t2        ) ending sleep
2016-11-22 15:16:59,241 (t1        ) ending sleep
2016-11-22 15:17:01,234 (t0        ) ending sleep
2016-11-22 15:17:01,235 (MainThread) joining t1
2016-11-22 15:17:01,235 (MainThread) joining t2
```